# how to add a clickable dropdown menu in blogger?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, blogspot

So, I found this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) on clickable dropdown menus but when I implement that, it doesn't work for some reason. I tried adding the html into the gadget but I don't know where to put the JavaScript in.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the same code used in the example you sent, you can get the javascript and insert at the end of the html between two script tags like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!-- javascript GOES HERE -->
<script>
```

Comment: thank you so much sure. i'll try this out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript code inside html putting it inside `<script></script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Create Drop down menu in blogger using add custom Gadget. In this you can add your own codes. This requires a little bit of CSS and HTML knowledge. Try my code to create drop down menu in blogger. referenced from this blogger [post](https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/2019/09/create-drop-down-menu-in-blogger.html)

```css
.dropdown-section1{
  border-radius:3px;
  width:80%;margin:0 auto;
  background:#607d8b;
  height:38px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(50,50,50,.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(50,50,50,.6);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(50,50,50,.6);
}
.dropdown-section1 .menu li a {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
.dropdown-section1 .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#607d8b;
 }
 .dropdown-section1 .menu li:last-child{
  border-right:none !important;
 }
.dropdown-section1 .menu .sub-menu li{
  float: none;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding: 10px;
 }
.dropdown-section1 .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width:100px;
  margin-left: -50px !important;
  margin-top: 10px !important;
 }
.dropdown-section1 .menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
 }
.dropdown-section1 .menu li:hover {
background:#94c018;
}
.dropdown-section1 .menu > li {
  border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown-section1 .place-right{
  left: 150px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-section1">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/" title="Category">Coose Niche</a>
</li><li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/" title="Category">Create Blog</a>
</li><li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/" title="Category">Moniter Blog</a>
</li><li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/" title="Category">DropDown</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/">String</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/">Array</a>
  
  <ul class="sub-menu place-right">
  <li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/">String</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/">Array</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/">Match</a></li>
 </ul>

  </li>
  <li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/">Match</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/" title="About Me">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="https://manimuthupandi.blogspot.com/" title="Contact Me">Reach Me</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```